# Sql Server how to store value of a field in another record

Tags: sql-server

I am pulling data from two databases using a UNION. I create a field called Ccode to indicate which database the record is from. I then create another field called Elmin using a CASE statement and populate it with the Balance field (another calculated field) based on the Account field.
What I would like to do is to take the value of the Elimn field for one record (where Account = 1113) and copy it to the record where Account = 3104 (I am off setting Receivables from one company with payable from the other)  Is there any way to do this?

I was thinking of using a variable, BUT I cannot seem to figure out how to put a calculated field into a variable when it would require such a complex Select statement (using joins and multiple fields and calculations)

*I DO NOT want to save the data!!* PLEASE do not give me an answer with Alter table or Insert etc. I only want to display the results.
Any ideas??

Current output:

```
Account      AcctName                    Ccode      Balance      Elmin
1112      Accounts Receivable - (U.S.)      C      1250923.94      0
1112      Accounts Receivable (U.S.)        U      0               0
1113      Accounts Receivable - I/C          U      223780.55      223780.55
3104      Accounts Payable - I/C            C      -254000         0
```

**Would like:**

```
Account      AcctName                    Ccode      Balance      Elmin
1112      Accounts Receivable - (U.S.)      C      1250923.94      0
1112      Accounts Receivable (U.S.)        U      0               0
1113      Accounts Receivable - I/C          U      223780.55      223780.55
3104      Accounts Payable - I/C            C      -254000        223780.55
```

**Code:**

```
SELECT        T1.Account, T2.AcctName, 'U' AS Ccode, SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) AS 'Balance', 

CASE 
    WHEN T1.Account IN (1113) THEN SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) ELSE 0 
END AS Elmin

FROM            OJDT AS T0 INNER JOIN
                         JDT1 AS T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId INNER JOIN
                         OACT AS T2 ON T1.Account = T2.AcctCode
WHERE        (CAST(T0.RefDate AS date) >= @Start_Date) AND (CAST(T0.RefDate AS date) <= @End_Date) AND (T2.GroupMask IN ('1', '2', '3'))
GROUP BY T1.Account, T2.AcctName, T2.GroupMask, T2.FatherNum

union all

SELECT        T1.Account, T2.AcctName, 'C' AS Ccode, SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) AS 'Balance', 

CASE WHEN T1.Account IN (1251) THEN SUM(T1.Debit - T1.Credit) ELSE 0 
END AS Elmin

FROM            CANADACO.dbo.OJDT AS T0 INNER JOIN
                         CANADACO.dbo.JDT1 AS T1 ON T0.TransId = T1.TransId INNER JOIN
                         CANADACO.dbo.OACT AS T2 ON T1.Account = T2.AcctCode
WHERE        (CAST(T0.RefDate AS date) >= @Start_Date) AND (CAST(T0.RefDate AS date) <= @End_Date) AND (T2.GroupMask IN ('1', '2', '3'))
GROUP BY T1.Account, T2.AcctName, T2.GroupMask, T2.FatherNum
ORDER BY T1.Account
```

Comment: I strongly suggest a better aliasing strategy. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: In the same way you have 1113 written in the code above the UNION ALL... could not 3104 be added explicitly as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap to those subqueries into common table expressions (CTE's). This would give you separate result sets to combine with `union all` and `cross apply`.

**Sample data**

Simplified data, but the `Elmin` can still be a calculated field.

```
declare @Database1Table table
(
    Account int,
    Ccode nvarchar(1),
    Elmin money
);
insert into @Database1Table (Account, Ccode, Elmin) values
(1112, 'U', 0.0),
(1113, 'U', 223780.55);

declare @Database2Table table
(
    Account int,
    Ccode nvarchar(1),
    Elmin money
);
insert into @Database2Table (Account, Ccode, Elmin) values
(1112, 'C', 0.0),
(3104, 'C', 0.0);
```

Simplified query, `Elmin` is calculated as a sum:

```
select d1.Account, d1.Ccode, sum(d1.Elmin) as Elmin
from @Database1Table d1
group by d1.Account, d1.Ccode
    union all
select d2.Account, d2.Ccode, sum(d2.Elmin) as Elmin
from @Database2Table d2
group by d2.Account, d2.Ccode
order by d1.Account;
```

Current result:

```
Account     Ccode Elmin
----------- ----- ---------------------
1112        C     0,00
1112        U     0,00
1113        U     223780,55
3104        C     0,00
```

**Solution**

Move the subqueries in two CTE's (`cte_d1` and `cte_d2`). Use a `cross apply` to fetch the replacement value for the `Account=3104` row (`case` expression).

```
with cte_d1 as
(
    select d1.Account, d1.Ccode, sum(d1.Elmin) as Elmin
    from @Database1Table d1
    group by d1.Account, d1.Ccode
),
cte_d2 as
(
    select d2.Account, d2.Ccode, sum(d2.Elmin) as Elmin
    from @Database2Table d2
    group by d2.Account, d2.Ccode
)
select c1.Account, c1.Ccode, c1.Elmin
from cte_d1 c1
  union all
select c2.Account, c2.Ccode, case c2.Account when '3104' then c4.Elmin else c2.Elmin end as Elmin
from cte_d2 c2
outer apply (   select top 1 c3.Elmin
                from cte_d1 c3
                where c3.Account = '1113' ) c4
order by c1.Account;
```

This gives:

```
Account     Ccode Elmin
----------- ----- ---------------------
1112        C     0,00
1112        U     0,00
1113        U     223780,55
3104        C     223780,55
```